# How to pass multi function inside the componentDidMount method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project and I need to get both users data and user's role from the backend so I created two API call like this.

```
loadUsers() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          users:response.data,
        })
      })
  }
```

and to get roles I created another method

```
loadRoles() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/roles')
      .then((response) => (
        this.setState({
          roles:response.data,
        })
      ))
  }
```

but when I call these methods inside the `componentDidMount()` method I get the following error

```
 ./src/views/Base/Users/Users.js
  Line 107:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

this is my state

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users:[],
      roles:[],
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is the `componentDidMount`? Show how you call them

Comment: `componentDidMount(){
    this.loadUsers(),
    this.loadRoles()
  } `

Comment: Why is it a comma? Hint: That is your bug.

Comment: What's on Line 107? Is it a Render function?

Comment: I put  comma to separate each function

Comment: Show componentDidMount() code and the Line 107 please, we need more information

Comment: In line 107 it's my componentDidMount() method

Comment: @hadi-alizada, epascarello already showed you your bug. You do use comma there, you need to use another character. Figure out which

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: oh thank you, shame :)